# How to check if a text file has gotten bigger?

Tags: python, for-loop

My idea was to create a script where I run multiple names from a list and then compare if it is in a `old_list`. If it's not in the list then we print out the name or call a function. Otherwise if it's not in the list, then I just wait 5-15 sec and check again if anything got added.

However my problem right now is that I have a list with random names:

**`names.txt`**

```
Craig  
Rebekah  
Zina  
Stella  
Zachary  
Ila  
Delsie  
Mauro  
Alba  
Antoniette
.... more
```

Using this script:

```
def script():

    old_list = []
    old_names_list = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('names.txt')]


    while True:
        new_names_list = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('newnames.txt')]

        #if new name added to the list, then we call a random function,
        #for example: def hello() or we can just print out the name
        #and we continue to do the below.
        for names in old_names_list:

            if names not in old_list:
                print(names)
                #Call a random function etc def hello():
                old_list.append(names)

        else:
            randomtime = random.randint(5, 15)
            print('No new names fouund! - retrying in {} secs'.format(randomtime))
            time.sleep(randomtime)
```

**`newnames.txt`**

```
Rebekah  
Zina  
Stella
```

Right now it does print out all the names in the list and then adds it into `old_list` and for the next search in the for loop it won't print out the name since it is inside the `old_list`. However what I want to do is that it should check `new_names_list` if it has added a new name in the list. If it has, it should search if the name is inside the names.txt and then print out the name that got added.

Output:

```
Prints out all the names and continue the while True loop.

*Adding Craig to newnames.txt*

print("Found Craig in the old_list!")

continue to search if new names got added.
```

Comment: One thing to note, use e.g. not Etc. Not related to the answer but I'm working on it

Comment: Oh im sorry! I will re-edit it! @Jachdich

Comment: How are names added to the `'newnames.txt'` file? What modifies it?

Comment: @martineau in the folder. You just manually add the names in the txt. file

Comment: OK, but I still don't quite understand what you want to happen instead of what it does in the code in your question. Please [edit] your question and try to make that clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?
It loops forever, printing all the names as it finds them.

```
def script():
    old_names_list = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('names.txt')]
    while True:
        new_names_list = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('newnames.txt')]

        if not new_names_list == old_names_list: #if there is a change
            hell() #call that function
            for i in new_names_list:
                if not i in old_names_list:
                    print(i)
            old_names_list = new_names_list

        else: #no change
            print("no change")
            time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: hmm, I think the issue is that it prints out all the newnames list. I just want to print out the one that got "changed"

Comment: OK, I'll make it do that if I can.

Comment: Appreciate it! Would mean alot for me! :)

Comment: I think this is it! :) Im gonna do some more work on it and see if it matches the results I want :)

Comment: Found and issue. So when I printed a name, it printed the name all the name.

Comment: hmm... Can you post an ideal output and the output that it gives? that would be very helpful

Comment: I think I solved it by adding `old_names_list = new_names_list` after the `if not i in old_names_list:`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185173/discussion-between-jachdich-and-hellosiroverthere).